# How to get result out of for loop

Tags: arrays, swift

I have a function in swift and I am using a for loop in it.

```
    let pointTF = [emailTF,passTF,resetEmailTF]

    for i in 0...pointTF.count
    {
        return coachMarksController.helper.makeCoachMark(for: pointTF[i])
    }
```

I want to return this value outside the loop? How can I do that? Please help

Comment: whats the need to return outside the loop? To return this one value you can set it to a variable and return it. to return all the results, add it to an array and return the array.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the above code is wrapped in a function you can define an array of `CoachMark` objects outside the scope of the for loop, and append the generated coachMark to the array:

```
var coachMarks: [CoachMark]()

for i in 0...pointTF.count
{
    var cm = coachMarksController.helper.makeCoachMark(for: pointTF[i])
    coachMarks.append(cm)
}

//Then you can return a single CoachMark:
return coachMarks[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't really know what you are returning, but if you want to return an array of the results you loop through, i suggest using a `map` for it, neat and simple.

```
return pointTF.map({ coachMarksController.helper.makeCoachMark(for: $0) })
```